# Page Not Importing/Executing Linked JavaScript when Using A Node.js Backend via WebStorm

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, webstorm

It's possible this is a bad way to do this, but I'm trying to do W3School's jQuery tutorial by importing the scripts to an HTML doc hosted on a Node server running via WebStorm.

I have installed and enabled the jQuery libraries under `Preferences > Languages & Frameworks > JavaScript > Libraries`. jQuery has been added to package.json and is listed under the *External Libraries* on the sidebar.

The project so far consists of three files: `node-server.js` (which of course creates the Node server), `main.html` (a blank-ish HTML doc), and `main.js` (the file containing our JS and jQuery). Their contents are as follows:

*`node-server.js`*

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

const PORT=1337;

var html = fs.readFileSync('main.html');

http.createServer(function (req, res)
{
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.end(html);
}).listen(PORT);
```

*`main.html`*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>W3Schools Learn jQuery Tutorial</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

*`main.js`*

```
$(document).ready( function ()
{
    var henlo = '<h1>henlo programer</h1>';
    var stinky = '<h1>helllo you STINKY PROGRAMMER</h1>';
    var ugly = '<h1>go build a website ugly</h1>';

    var body = $('body');
    body.append(henlo);
    body.append(stinky);
    body.append(ugly);
});
```

Loading the page returns a DOM containing only the contents of `main.html`. Importing JS of any kind seems to fail, as a simple .js doc containing a simple instruction like `alert('asdf')` does not execute. Writing `alert('asdf')` or the contents of `main.js` directly into `<script>` tags on the page executes both scripts.

There's probably something obvious I'm missing, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending only the html file to the client regardless of the url it is asking for. 
Make a switch case and respond with the file it's asking for.

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs'); 
const PORT=1337;
var html = fs.readFileSync('main.html');
var js = fs.readFileSync('main.js');

var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) { 
    switch (req.url) { 
        case "/main.js" :
            res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/javascript"});
            res.write(js);
            break;
         default :
            res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"}); 
            res.write(html); 
    }
    res.end(); 
}).listen(PORT);
```

When you first load the page, default case gets executed and responds with the html file. But as you are providing link to the js file in it, the browser again makes a request to localhost:/main.js and gets the js file.

Consider using frameworks like express js

Comment: Thank you, that's got it! I'll look into using Express for this instead. One thing, though: I think the `);` on the line before `res.end()` in your solution may be extraneous.